# Rails 7 RestClient::Not found in find_each loop updating avatar from Microsoft Graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microsoft-graph-api, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to attach all pictures from the Microsoft Graph to my new Rails application using active storage and the rest-client gem.

It works for a single user I do it like this:

`User.find_by_email("user.email@domain.com).avatar.attach io:StringIO.open(image.to_blob), filename: "avatar.jpg", content_type: metadata["mimeType"], identify: false`

But in a batch loop, it doesn't work.

```
class RestController < ApplicationController
    require 'rest-client'     

    def sync_azure_picture
        @token = RestController.get_azure_token

        User.find_each do |currentUser|
            request_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/'+currentUser[:id_azure]+'/photo/$value'

            puts request_url

            resp = RestClient.get(request_url,'Authorization' => @token)

            image = MiniMagick::Image.read(resp.body)
            metadata = image.data

            currentUser.avatar.attach io:StringIO.open(image.to_blob), filename: "avatar.jpg", content_type: metadata["mimeType"], identify: false
        end
    end
end`
```

The error i'm getting is

> RestClient::NotFound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not all users have attachments? You can log errors and then check these urls

```rb
User.find_each do |user|
  # ...
rescue RestClient::NotFound => e
  Rails.logger.error("#{request_url}:")
  Rails.logger.error(e)
end
```

Comment: Awsome! So simple but so powerfull!

Comment: @michnicov I cannot upvote yet because my question was not upvoted enough. I just created my stack overflow account, a bit ridiculous if you ask me. I need 15 reputation to vote.